# How to show an svg image after download in Maui

Tags: image, svg, maui

In our app we use svg image files that are partially embedded resources but are also loaded by a RestService, since most of these icons can be added and named by the user himself.
The embedded resources are not an problem, you can change file extantion from  .svg to .png with an converter but this don't work with svg images from url or mabe from Microsoft.Maui.Storage.FileSystem.AppDataDirectory or Environment.SpecialFolder.LocalApplicationData path. Our Xamrin.forms app used the FFImageLoading library to do this but we migrate this app now to .net Maui and I can't find any other way to show the svg images. Is there anyone out there that can help me and has a good solution to this problem.

That's the way we download the svg files:

```
      private async Task DownloadIcons(List<DownloadIcon> downloadIcons)
      {
        var lightIconsFolderPath = Path.Combine(iconFolderPath, lightIconFolderName);
        var darkIconsFolderPath = Path.Combine(iconFolderPath, darkIconFolderName);

        DirectoryManager(lightIconsFolderPath);
        DirectoryManager(darkIconsFolderPath);

        CurrentIcons = new List<Icon>();

        foreach (var downloadIcon in downloadIcons)
        {
            Icon icon = new Icon();
            icon.IconId = downloadIcon.IconId;

            var ligthIconBytes = await 
            DownloadIconFromURL(downloadIcon.LightThemeIconLink);
            icon.LightThemeIconPath = await WriteIconToDisk(lightIconsFolderPath, ligthIconBytes, downloadIcon.IconTranslations[0].Name);
            
            var darkIconBytes = await DownloadIconFromURL(downloadIcon.DarkThemeIconLink);
            icon.DarkThemeIconPath = await WriteIconToDisk(darkIconsFolderPath, darkIconBytes, downloadIcon.IconTranslations[0].Name);
            

            CurrentIcons.Add(icon);
        }
    }       

     private async Task<byte[]> DownloadIconFromURL(string downloadedIconUrl)
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] bytes;
            using (HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient())
            {
                bytes = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(downloadedIconUrl);
            }
            
            return bytes;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Exception while trying to download icon from url", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Here we write icons to disk:

```
     private async Task<string> WriteIconToDisk(string pathToIconsFolder, byte[] iconBytes, string iconName)
    {
        try
        {
            string fileName = "";
            string namingConventionName = ModifyLowerCaseLetterString(iconName);
           
            fileName = Path.Combine(pathToIconsFolder, $"{namingConventionName}.svg");
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, iconBytes);
            return fileName;
        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        {
            log.Error("Exception while trying to write icon on device", e);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

The image at xaml:

```
     <Image HeightRequest="24" Source="{Binding Icon.ActiveIconPath, Converter={StaticResource SvgImageSourceConverter}}"
            WidthRequest="24" />
```

At the end after I chased it through the converter, the imagesource get an path like this: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/[company]/files/icons/light/light.png
I also tryed it with .svg instead of .png.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After downloading the `SVG image` in your local directory, you can directly refer to it as a `PNG` in your XAML and you don't need convert it to an `PNG` file which makes that work across all the platforms:

```
<Image 
    Source="svgfilename.png"
    SemanticProperties.Description="The SVG image scaled to a 100x100 PNG"
    WidthRequest="100"
    HeightRequest="100" />
```

Comment: Yes, sorry I write that wrong, my converter don' t convert the file to png, he only change the extension  from .svg to .png.

Comment: Then there's no need to convert the extension from .svg to .png, you can directly refer to it as a PNG in your XAML.